# Simple list-merging question (redux)

Tags: list-manipulation

How can I combine `headers` and `data` to yield `desiredResult`?

```
headers = {"heading-1", "heading-2", "heading-3"};

data = Delete[#, 0] & /@ 
   Map[Partition[#, 4] &, 
    Table[Map[#1 <> ToString[i] &, 
      Partition[Alphabet[], 20], {2}], {i, 3}] , {2}];

desiredResult = {{{"heading-1", SpanFromLeft, SpanFromLeft, 
     SpanFromLeft}, {"a1", "b1", "c1", "d1"}, {"e1", "f1", "g1", 
     "h1"}, {"i1", "j1", "k1", "l1"}, {"m1", "n1", "o1", "p1"}, {"q1",
      "r1", "s1", "t1"}}, {{"heading-2", SpanFromLeft, SpanFromLeft, 
     SpanFromLeft}, {"a2", "b2", "c2", "d2"}, {"e2", "f2", "g2", 
     "h2"}, {"i2", "j2", "k2", "l2"}, {"m2", "n2", "o2", "p2"}, {"q2",
      "r2", "s2", "t2"}}, {{"heading-3", SpanFromLeft, SpanFromLeft, 
     SpanFromLeft}, {"a3", "b3", "c3", "d3"}, {"e3", "f3", "g3", 
     "h3"}, {"i3", "j3", "k3", "l3"}, {"m3", "n3", "o3", "p3"}, {"q3",
      "r3", "s3", "t3"}}};

{ {"headers", Grid[{headers}, Frame -> All]}, {"data", 
   Map[Grid[#, Frame -> All] &, data, {1}]}, {"result", 
   Map[Grid[#, Frame -> All] &,  desiredResult]}} // Column
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
desired = PadRight[#, Automatic, SpanFromLeft]& /@ Join[List /@ List /@ headers, data, 2];

Grid[#, Frame -> All] & /@ desired
```

[image]

Alternatively,

```
desired2 = Join[List /@ PadRight[List /@ headers, {3, 4}, SpanFromLeft], data,  2];
desired2 == desired
```

> True

Comment: That was quick. Thanks!

Comment: @Calvin, you are welcome. Thank you for the accept.